# R: Openstreetmap autoplot transparency of map

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap

I am trying to use the `Openstreetmap` package from R to build a ggplot figure with a map as its base layer. It seems to be a very straightforward approach, except that I can't figure out how to set a transparency value for the map (similar to alpha in ggplot). Any ideas/workaround highly appreciated (with the use of ggplot).

MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(OpenStreetMap)
mp <- openmap(c(47.42549,8.471872),
          c(47.33238,8.592878), zoom=NULL,type='osm')
autoplot(mp)
```

Comment: would `ggmap`also work for you or does it have to be `Openstreetmap`?

Comment: Have a look at `osmplotr` to create highly customizable versions of `OpenStreetMap`

Comment: it can be any package, as long as it allows to project the map to WGS84, and can be added as a layer to a ggplot.